# Centering Div Class in Google Optimize

Tags: html, css, google-optimize

I'm working on some A/B testing in Google Optimizing and I'm really struggling to center a div class I have.

This is the entire HTML for the div class:

```
    <div class="twelve columns center additional_content" style="center">
        <p><b>Additional Content</b></p>
    </div>
```

I've tried several things including adding the following CSS:

```
    div.additional_content>p {
        text-align : center;
    }
```

However, the div class is still not centering on the page. I know there are other channels on here asking about centering a div class, but it appears Google Optimize has different formatting to their CSS.

Any ideas?

Comment: I've not worked with Google Optimize, but your CSS is certainly valid, and centers your text correctly in a regular context. Are you sure that your rules are being applied correctly? You can use the F12 Developer Tools to check whether your rule is applied (and if there is another rule overriding yours).

Comment: @ObsidianAge Where do I look in Dev Tools to check if the rule is being applied? Love this idea, but don't know where to look. Thank you!

Comment: Update, think it's here: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/coverage/

Answer (score 0):

Try `margin: 0 auto` sometimes this works better for centering